# How to solve "Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js" in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I did "npm install react-navigation" and imported "import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';" but it still says "Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js"

How can I fix it and make it work?

Thank you

Comment: You need to install is seperately: `npm install @react-navigation/stack`

Comment: It still says "Unable to resolve "react-native-safe-area-context"

Answer (score 1):

Does `@react-navigation/stack` gets install when you install `react-navigation`? because I don't see anything in `package.json`

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/package.json

I think you will have to install `@react-navigation/stack` manually using below

`npm install @react-navigation/stack react-native-safe-area-context`

FYI,
Previously they had 3 things required for installation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack, which is not mentioned in the new version.

If you still face issue of some unknown package being not available then try to check the old docs.

Comment: It still says "Unable to resolve "react-native-safe-area-context"

Comment: Seems like there are few peer dependencies as well. Edited my code.